# Using two contradicting present participles in the same clause, and or but?

Tags: verbs

In a sentence I wrote, there are two present-participle verbs, yet they have contradicting meanings. Should "and" be used in between them or "but"?

Example:

> "Let me go!" I shout, **struggling** to be free **but** **availing**.

or

> "Let me go!" I shout, **struggling** to be free **and availing**.

Are both grammatically correct, or should a different coordinator be used?

(I did attempt to research this but all results either gave the definition of "contradict" or explained what the "present participle" is.)

Comment: What is it you intend to mean with your use of *availing*?

Comment: In general you choose *but* when you are adding restrictions to a previously stated condition (reducing its scope).  You choose *and* when enlarging the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!

I believe you mean to use the word *prevailing* instead of *availing*, as availing is defined as making use of an opportunity or benefit, whereas prevailing means to be victorious over opposing forces; since you are struggling and wresting yourself free in your sentence, I suggest you use *prevailing.*

In regard to which sentence construction is correct, I recommend you state your act of availing (or prevailing) in a separate sentence, and simply ending the sentence after "free."